# How to catch when a user leaves the page in Meteor and/or Iron router?

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to catch when **a user leaves** from my Meteor application (version 1.2.0.2) ; something equivalent to the `SocketIO disconnect()` on the server side.

The user could **close his browser, go to another website or simply refresh the page** and it would fire anyway

Surprisingly, i'm searching on Internet and everything is mixed up, nothing works properly. I thought Meteor was literally based on *this magic-live processing* so it must manage this event in a way or another.

**Iron router** documentation specify this :

> onStop: Called when the route is stopped, typically right before a new
>   route is run.

I also found `Router.load` and `Router.unload` but none of them work. This is my current [not working] code which is quite simple

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'MasterLayout'
  loadingTemplate: 'Loading'
  notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound'

Router.onStop (->

  console.log('Try to stop')
  Users.insert({

    name: "This is a test"
    lat: 0
    lng: 0

    })

)
```

**Am I doing something wrong here ? How do you catch this event in my app ?**

Comment: Are you trying to send something from the client to the server when the user leaves or are do you just want the server to know when the user's connection is lost? It is not necessarily easy.

Comment: I want to detect it to be 100% he left. what's the difference between the 2 methods ? the client could obviously fail to deliver the "message" and that could be break a whole system, what would you do if you really needed this data to change a collection ?

Comment: I wouldn't count on anything coming from the client, not only security-wise, but also considering that unexpected things happen. Abrupt disconnects, browser crashes and navigation when using the polling WebSocket fallback may seem the same from the server's perspective. There is no real way that I know of to detect when a user leaves your website. I would probably change the state based on the DDP connection status on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two solution working, I found the 2nd and best one by searching in the [API Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) for a while.

### First solution : working with subscribe & publish

Anywhere in the controller / front-end side you must subscribe to a collection

```
# in coffee
@subscribe('allTargets')

# in javascript
this.subscribe('allTargets')
```

Afterwards you just have to publish and add a `onStop` listener. This example will take a `Targets` collection I already defined somewhere before, it just gets all the entries.

```
# in coffee
Meteor.publish 'allTargets', ->

  @onStop ->

    # Do your stuff here

  return Targets.find()

# in javascript
Meteor.publish('allTargets', function() {

  this.onStop(function() {

      // Do your stuff here

  });

  return Targets.find();

});
```

You have to be careful not to `return Targets.find()` before you set the `onStop` listener too. I don't think it's a perfect solution since you don't listen to the connection itself but the changes of a collection.

### Second solution : working with DDP connection

I realized through the Meteor [API Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection) we can directly listen to the connection and see if someone disconnect from the server-side.

To stay well-organized and clean within my [Meteor Iron](https://github.com/iron-meteor) project I added a new file in `app/server/connection.coffee` and wrote this code

```
# in coffee
Meteor.onConnection (connection) ->

  connection.onClose ->

    # Do your stuff

# in javascript
Meteor.onConnection(function(connection) {

  connection.onClose(function() {

    // Do your stuff

  });

});
```

You can manage datas with `connection.id` which's the unique identifier of your browser tab. Both solutions are working well for me.

> If you use `Meteor.userId` through their accounts system, you can't use it  outside a `method` in the server-side so I had to find a workaround with the `connection.id`.

If anyone has a better solution to manage connections while getting this kind of client datas, don't hesitate to give your input.

Comment: I'm trying to do the 2nd approach and need access to the user. How did you use the connection id to get access to the user? I can't access the usersSessions which seems to store both the user id and connection id because some other package already created that Collection and it's not accessible outside.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach to the `onStop` of the route, not the router. For instance:

```
Router.route('/', {
    onStop: function() {
        console.log("someone left the '/' route");
    }
});
```

Another option is to use the `onStop` [event of subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_onstop). That is probably the option most similar to the socketio disconnect you mentioned. You can find [an example of that in the typhone source code](https://github.com/chfritz/typhone/blob/master/app/server/main.js#L64).

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i'm trying to make it as simple as possible because i'm still learning all this so i kept trying with the route, the way you said and it still doesn't work (i added a `load` in the same route and it's correctly firing, but not the `onStop` ... Any idea ? It really doesn't work here ...

Comment: now i changed the place and moved it to the `lib/controllers/home_controller.coffee` which was **generated** by iron and contains a `onStop` i noticed. Still doesn't work ... Basically their own function doesn't seem to work

Comment: Doesn't the Route onStop run client side?  publish.onStop is what you need on the server.

Comment: Can you detail your answer ? I'm still struggling and searching, but i can't find a workaround